# ng-modal button click to main window data not passing (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular8

I was working on NG-Model window. Initially my code was working; when my code was applied in select element that is radio button, it was working perfectly fine, but when I changed my code to Click method for the button it was not working.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let columns"> <input type="radio" name="age" (change)="getageValue(columns)" value="ageValue"> </td>
```

But If I changed to onClick of Button

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="getageValue(columns)">Match</button>
```

My guess was that column property was not there.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show more of your code?
do you have columns var in your button scope?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmbmti) that I create based on your question. and I can't find any errors on it.
Am I missing something?
(Sample code applied to last column as "Example Columns".)